# typedef variable in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

i want to ask about typedef variable in C++

ok, right now i'm using PCL and i want to separate the code into .h and .cpp

here's my .h file

```
template <typename PointType>
class OpenNIViewer
{
public:
    typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointType> Cloud;
    typedef typename Cloud::ConstPtr CloudConstPtr;

    ...
    ...

    CloudConstPtr getLatestCloud ();

    ...
    ...
};
```

then the definition of getLatestCloud() on other .cpp file

```
template <typename PointType>
CloudConstPtr OpenNIViewer<PointType>::getLatestCloud ()
{
    ...
}
```

then i got C4430 error because it doesn't recognize return type CloudConstPtr

sorry for the silly question :D

Answer (score 2):

`CloudConstPtr` is a nested type, so you need qualify it with the scope also:

```
template <typename PointType>
typename OpenNIViewer<PointType>::CloudConstPtr OpenNIViewer<PointType>::getLatestCloud ()
{
    ...
}
```

But then it still would **not** work: it is because you've defined it in `.cpp` file. In case of template, the definition should be available in `.h` file itself. The simpliest way to do that is to define each member function in the class itself. Don't write `.cpp` file.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the answer, anyway, i found out template class shouldn't be separated to .h and .cpp

i should put them all on a single .h instead :D

Comment: @RezaAdhityaSaputra: Yes. Put them all in single `.h` file

Answer (score 1):

Change `getLatestCloud` to:

```
template <typename PointType>
typename OpenNIViewer<PointType>::CloudConstPtr
OpenNIViewer<PointType>::getLatestCloud ()
{
    ...
}
```

When reading `CloudConstPtr`, the compiler does not yet know which scope it should be looking in, so it needs to be qualified.